# Not able to scrap data from a website that contains cookies

Tags: scala, web-scraping, jsoup

I'm trying to scrap data from site (https://www.notary.org/find-notary-in-pa), but when I scrap it, it don't provide all data. It is just showing some tags related to Cookies and giving 403 Forbidden status.

I'm using JSOUP Browser for scraping. Scala Version 2.13.1, sbt version 1.2.8. Libraries are:

```
  "org.jsoup" % "jsoup" % "1.15.3",
  "net.ruippeixotog" %% "scala-scraper" % "3.1.0",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.6.0"
```

**Code:**

```
object Scrapping extends App {
  implicit val actorSystem = ActorSystem()
  implicit val executionContext = actorSystem.dispatcher

  val url = "https://www.notary.org/find-notary-in-pa"
  val postBody = "search=1&page=1&zip=17739&radius=60&language=16"

  val request = HttpRequest(HttpMethods.GET, url, Nil, HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, postBody))
  val responseFuture = Http(actorSystem).singleRequest(request)

  responseFuture
    .onComplete {
      case Success(res) =>
        Unmarshal(res.entity.toStrict(180 seconds)).value.map { result =>
          val htmlStr = result.data.utf8String
          val browser = JsoupBrowser()

          val doc = browser.parseString(htmlStr)
          println(doc)
        }

      case Failure(ex) => println(ex)
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Result is: HttpResponse(403 Forbidden,List(Date: Tue, 23 May 2023 07:06:27 GMT, Connection: close, Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy: require-corp, Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin, Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy: same-origin, Permissions-Policy: accelerometer=(),autoplay=(),camera=(),clipboard-read=(),clipboard-write=(),fullscreen=(),geolocation=(),gyroscope=(),hid=(),interest-cohort=(),magnetometer=(),microphone=(),payment=(),publickey-credentials-get=(),screen-wake-lock=(),serial=(),sync-xhr=(),usb=(), Referrer-Policy: same-origin, X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN, cf-mitigated: challenge, Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0, Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT, Set-Cookie: __cf_bm=TuSooVGckTYfAah9niitr0C1oKMzwmGk9UsfWpJHdRg-1684825587-0-ATSrfKj+GI29HRhxUhYI3JZogpDlsuanvRgMk9/LxtJafWZuj6iBT+IVlEaoaiEjDzARomApIEr1z1/kHJfgcMA=; Expires=Tue, 23 May 2023 07:36:27 GMT; Domain=notary.org; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=None, Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000, X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff, Server: cloudflare, CF-RAY: 7cbb74d2bf2d3e11-SIN, alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=86400, h3-29=":443"; ma=86400),HttpEntity.Chunked(text/html; charset=UTF-8),HttpProtocol(HTTP/1.1))
JsoupDocument(<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">
 <head>
  <title>Just a moment...</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <link href="/cdn-cgi/styles/challenges.css" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>
 <body class="no-js">
  <div class="main-wrapper" role="main">
   <div class="main-content">
    <noscript>
     <div id="challenge-error-title">
      <div class="h2"><span class="icon-wrapper">
        <div class="heading-icon warning-icon"></div></span> <span id="challenge-error-text"> **Enable JavaScript and cookies to continue** </span>
      </div>
     </div>
    </noscript>
    <div id="trk_jschal_js" style="display:none;background-image:url('/cdn-cgi/images/trace/managed/nojs/transparent.gif?ray=7cbb74d2bf2d3e11')"></div>
    <form id="challenge-form" action="/find-notary-in-pa?__cf_chl_f_tk=mzA0LtFJcmd954jQkwGGg2Zzqbn3aeGQXQBSQ0lTC44-1684825587-0-gaNycGzNCrs" method="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"><input type="hidden" name="md" value="nJ1WvaqILFMtNShMcFUR1cGMc4UmUTHiDhcQZiIk4gA-1684825587-0-AWrtgrxHKfhAgNg303P9u3ReRZNLaurxA-QImsVsfcfZ870n9iZv8faPd5WzdmXmG2sODz7B9HneeAXwx8Tlv9mZKJhPIzArPWBkMnvKk-W9NEcCMubmHGYXeURwNARwsuVg5w0Tpr7ANAp3iEiC7pnZvkbVGtzvUZJL86JZpG_HN6787yhuFzKk7oWukuknCA7AhP_Z685TBaNtklYwI5NA7q04PKKeDkKK6MTWQoL09RgsdQgx0EWo936GrwWykyoh3xwoprQg1xsuhrzAhAuzumsugc-YEHdTAg8KKZGScX_eJqrlb2Z-WnCAvbkGpFLV5ZDdtlVEYI50pcI26ihSL-Vah49Kl2UxT7VlRsL6YTzb3Xt3gDlK_ZgEutNpEEmy76CyvPGqcpjcg0Pa1tSVkGbQ93AlYLL8FyyHBoZ2e19s-TqwrRY-Bl_FN3UUn6jUqFstYfYGnZ9wQxrYi8wRsFGPIaJNbzQ4Fx7EjP3bqsNjxtfjNnr6IYwfxK3X21GPxoEag6x1QUyOZ2KmDf7tVy8CyJ3QIdhOmcNJgbYAmLCFgCb3b2zE6R7yG3RYzWVjtJq2wRswjptoSmP-fGinc0YdIIfyFCeSBFB9r5RxXyXRbzEhTtz4j-TxtMsBc7l0tQhO6KhMlc6XFac0wogUXoYXKm4lcOCQhDYOI91Kg1CpbuzWYThwklnepFpk95cgxzk-xWL-YD6TmN0Em9lN4s9fPIouO6o_KQEmzIH5vZyXij0D9vQ9a9-TH4gOyPn2GWrMySEtFqR16PHpu9ojhK-scan6QAd_fmL5sMROMSIzC8ndQw-Dhr4FlNEyRt33rpuqaiVaZcQRUHLNi84pm8Kb9zBnBhwsauC3g1RViT9q3-lAHKgBX4y0DmAYL6iRazKHxFDrTUhNVBdnYmzUurrGiLfXn6_-jawKul9gGP1bYKt9eF7V4ikh9ymd1__887DbP36i_Vstf9d1kfUlrCl3Wcd5DAInkyVA4r0voxn8ryoPj_sZgeC2DM0JhoiJrSSQebXhmFRWDfPgiO8zE_tphlxE41PiwpGLKAlsdtXg677xUVG0DJ7j-tqftt7zTe14MyEjVBA3sAs7nv7sxadOErp2aSzFFuTQqVrLaR4N0wvxNtukPXY-_CbmYqufpGeK0jDamWwHvxj3GvTmdnbbRIBqr1C_eigKEhJij8jXIIm7DwqRC_PglHHFhnvV708TeAMlGdhhyFa53HBXujyVQ1GmZTYdZzL15Z2pZNi2Xd5A9awQz7qBWWMbTgurE4YunlnqYHJUuKLFpWVzqA8ulmSAktJKdLOQBx0-S1rVZOnn4S4ac8kjplOdXqpgZnv5q2JiWjkR5-GlDH21qkxbmKQ5i3Sb7U0SRM_ca_TfbJUQa3kCi_ZyFPYjnoNQ186d6MsMddde4_tdXjnBR36k5qIkzNc1bc_2jnKt5CKUBLc4jlDqKUqHqJxV42uz72oXkWf6H31Q0Ol5_08KwJM75o89Ku4oXer_50_4Nl09bYJqvs_kxXQVA56OlYc7jRyZTKoEtJ0r_xwSDRe3IAss6bhLYKXaHs8xI16INHVT4W6jKvu5eCuTTFZq3Fr16yvdVOZtrvOHvc7qxHhuJR9FIczKtwnUD2xxrBi5ZRAcPZLWVNuBZZc20z3CbzogBhP4b2DZ98zWyoOZn_fDH8oDrxGJLIbNp9kDCVd1cNZyN461MF2nCT94Q1zqkrU24ntnpRZyd-TRtLt1ZQIJC64aQFQ6dUWvszd768O3YK4_Ejr9m9Y-xDcbMl0hoMYqIUXxUK80xF-5nv0relWsfuLJC0GsSkONQSPV7ryVT6Y-ZQluUDu0wa6HhFEVdtsA6-xfF9IrNMRoqGc_Vgo2rIjOypZoFXeQsWmPQ0f0mQDDx9IDeL7gEtOqurfGA6BbMK73tR_WKpGERr40CB9flEukmfolN7AWAHDqXzzAAqItPTizivnKvLUPBrsLYnIEYAxqUINh5ymai9Dp6aFhtbxB_Aj5pwxUIgBACa2umXRkn4MeYRJKiviP6yrhaYwHFufBat0zeEBaXw5PVOWtg0FS7c7Vqm_YedDXGM3BsNihRFkC7u5WvoH0In-OPP0iIj-b8J8nSf_iMH5MSATG7pOITITGzFEQZ-Impcbpobd08GFj8nA6D_LmUJn-DQwOTtaFSHvigIhZOArqXIT60J-SWL3F_yKWY8ryKNrG73R1t8RBrg25jyGhOdpVjW7FcQ5QF0aJdTIb7isCjyO3pWtLP6z9IgAadiiK6gKLurbijc9b8yMgxetvh7ZoXlYMZsby06d20bHRNnoikjgVHnuNTdHKuBbzYM4bruQ19nC5GtpaaN11iY5ijIC4938Qvv4SgzvTeymgjRBf5hra5fQGCpj-zg0aw2CXsCawu-vOpnNdWdyv2TSJd63yd8Yea6orMDCUq9XGEM9byBA74XGXW3NiALZNaaNtr5EdY8zYSdKHWyWmaAoT3EWQ2KIqhWGk0u4PjDksgiJ0V5aFjA7FtDCAHSAI20IgDBh3E_llhq6_f5cP1r3Fr9EIWcnTZJ3Vo0oug7SOjE-KpXpkclAsR3zzcDMULBPACWhIFAcTQmIqEeJAPX4VcwTrexnv52R7E-u7QWC6U3GPlAqmputHUe2tGsoNjtmHVccQ94RJZV0EwRSR5eUiKzfz9g">
    </form>
   </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    (function(){
        window._cf_chl_opt={
            cvId: '2',
            cZone: 'www.notary.org',
            cType: 'managed',
            cNounce: '36364',
            cRay: '7cbb74d2bf2d3e11',
            cHash: '0876cddef58b092',
            cUPMDTk: "\/find-notary-in-pa?__cf_chl_tk=mzA0LtFJcmd954jQkwGGg2Zzqbn3aeGQXQBSQ0lTC44-1684825587-0-gaNycGzNCrs",
            cFPWv: 'g',
            cTTimeMs: '1000',
            cMTimeMs: '0',
            cTplV: 5,
            cTplB: 'cf',
            cK: "",
            cRq: {
                ru: 'aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cubm90YXJ5Lm9yZy9maW5kLW5vdGFyeS1pbi1wYQ==',
                ra: 'YWtrYS1odHRwLzEwLjUuMA==',
                rm: 'R0VU',
                d: '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',
                t: 'MTY4NDgyNTU4Ny42NDAwMDA=',
                m: 'RWzYlPRZimxpXnV+Ok32Drp7tqqrES7kFBNLAqI0F1g=',
                i1: 'sozLHntPXTz9PQ4wzuktCA==',
                i2: '3t5LBNk/LaKKkb3hV3e8Vg==',
                zh: 'QDDCfzYW/V6DJqiXxEib4/bX/N/adiROm17oM15CsJ0=',
                uh: 'dbtoyss6cKQ5ac+XnrLsI5fzxWgILrm/0biBi8QBNIA=',
                hh: 'XSI0SJ45mJgsxl7hbL8o6VZfDefWKJBB8nwdi/1JZmw=',
            }
        };
        var trkjs = document.createElement('img');
        trkjs.setAttribute('src', '/cdn-cgi/images/trace/managed/js/transparent.gif?ray=7cbb74d2bf2d3e11');
        trkjs.setAttribute('alt', '');
        trkjs.setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
        document.body.appendChild(trkjs);
        var cpo = document.createElement('script');
        cpo.src = '/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/h/g/orchestrate/managed/v1?ray=7cbb74d2bf2d3e11';
        window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUHash = location.hash === '' && location.href.indexOf('#') !== -1 ? '#' : location.hash;
        window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUQuery = location.search === '' && location.href.slice(0, location.href.length - window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUHash.length).indexOf('?') !== -1 ? '?' : location.search;
        if (window.history && window.history.replaceState) {
            var ogU = location.pathname + window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUQuery + window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUHash;
            history.replaceState(null, null, "\/find-notary-in-pa?__cf_chl_rt_tk=mzA0LtFJcmd954jQkwGGg2Zzqbn3aeGQXQBSQ0lTC44-1684825587-0-gaNycGzNCrs" + window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUHash);
            cpo.onload = function() {
                history.replaceState(null, null, ogU);
            };
        }
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(cpo);
    }());
</script>
 </body>
</html>)
```

Help me in this. Is it problem of cookies (we need to enable cookies) or something else?

How can I solve this?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The issue seems more related to JavaScript: _Enable JavaScript_. This is likely a webpage that is rendered by JavaScript in the browser. If you aim to parse it, you need a tool that is able to execute JavaScript.

Comment: Can you tell me which tools can I use?